# State is not getting updated in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs

```
class ViewExchange extends React.Component{ 
  state={list:[],refresh:false}
  componentWillMount(props){

    if(_.isEmpty(Cookies.get())){
     this.props.history.push("/signup")
    }
    else{
      console.log("is present")
    let platform = Cookies.get('platform')
    console.log(platform)
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/user/viewexchange',{platform})
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({list:res.data})})
    
    console.log(this.state.list)
    }
  }


 render(){
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={()=>this.setState({refresh:true})}>refresh</button>
          {console.log(this.state.refresh)}
        </div>
    );
      }
}
export default withRouter(ViewExchange);
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated, use `componentDidMount`. Also, you can't `console.log` the state on the line immediately after you change it, because state changes are asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

`setState` state update operations are async, so it will take a bit of time to update the state. But your log executes before it updates. Instead you can make use of passing function as a second param in the setState:

```
this.setState({list:res.data}, () => console.log(this.state.list))
```

another way is:

```
this.setState(state => {
     state.list = res.data
}, () => console.log(this.state.list))
```

Comment: `setState` is ***not*** an async function, but react state updates ***are*** asynchronous. It's not clear if this is what you meant, but since `async` has a very specific meaning in javascript it's best to disambiguate.

Comment: @DrewReese yes, what i mean was the same

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Jai's answer is correct, I also don't believe you are initialising your state correctly.

As you're using a class component you must initialise the state within the class's constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { 
     list: [],
     refreshing: false,
   };

}
```